# SQL Server / ADO / money format and comma conversions

Tags: sql-server, ado

I retrieve data from SQL Server table data uding ADO.

Ok I have money formats data, but internally my array uses float values (in fact I can do right math operations...)

That is, I have something like : (pseudocode)

```
my_array(pos)= rs.fields("money_field") (retrieving data)
my_array(pos)*=0.87 (a 87 % discount).   (modify)
rs.fields("money_field")= my_array(pos); update; (updating data)
```

When I want to update data from my ado recordset to SQL Server, the float values (I have a point as a separator (VB)) has been changed in SQL Server to a number multiplied by 100.

Money data have (2 decimals).

How can I convert or what have I to do to update correct values ?
(from ADO of course....)

Any help ? I have almost finished my app, this is the last issue.

Thanks

Comment: You are using money in db and convert it to floats in your app? Come on. Did you ever try the infamous 2 - sqrt(2) * sqrt(2)? Please, for your own sake, don't do that.

Comment: mm. I can follow any advise.... I use the values to calculate some statistics... And i have not monney format in VB...

Comment: Don't you have something like decimal or numeric in plain old VB?

Comment: But in case I want to use floats (or doubles). How can I update a money field ? Have I to use a string data with $prefix or something like this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are converting it in sql server.. this way you can do it.

```
PARSENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(amount) AS MONEY),1),2)
```

EX: Amount=10000

Result will be 10,000